# Setting author permission to update posts in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a flask blog and I want to restrict updating of posts to only the author of that post.

This is my database schema:

```py
class Users(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    'users', MetaData(bind=None),

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    allposts = relationship('Posts', back_populates='users')
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Users('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"
```

```py
class Posts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    'posts', MetaData(bind=None),
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ........
    author = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    
    users = relationship('Users', back_populates='allposts')
    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Posts('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
       return s.query(Users).get(int(user_id))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This is my update route:

```py
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>/update", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update_post(post_id):
    s = session()
    post = s.query(Posts, Users).join(Users, Posts).filter(Users.id)
    if Posts.users != current_user.id:
        abort(403)
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        post.title = form.title.data
        post.content = form.content.data
        s.commit()

        flash('Your post has been updated!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('postview', post_id=post.id))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.title.data = post.title
        form.content.data = post.content
    return render_template('newpost.html', title='Update Post',
                           form=form, legend='Update Post')
```

How can I limit the updating right to the author?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra check for limiting the author to update the post after first `if`.

```
if Posts.users != current_user.id:
    abort(403)
if Posts.author != current_user.id:
    flash('Only Author can update the post', 'warning')
    return redirect(url_for('postview', post_id=post.id))
```